# Background image responsive without getting cropped

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I've already made the background image to full size in my page, but when I inspect and try to display it in phone mode, my background image get cropped, how can I resist this thing so it can't get cropped but always cover particular part of the page

```
<div class="inner-banner has-base-color-overlay text-center" style="background: url(header.jpg); background-size: cover; position: center;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <h3>About Us</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to use `media-quires` with `background-position` and `background-size` options with values

Answer (score 0):

If you are using background image and You want see in mobile view then it will be cut off of the background image you need to call img src.

Comment: this should be in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
    .header-img {
    max-width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    }
    @media all and (max-width:600px){
    .header-img {
    height:300px;
    object-fit:cover;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="inner-banner has-base-color-overlay text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
                <img src="images/header.jpg" class="header-img" alt="">
                <h3>About Us</h3>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set these css for BackGround Image :

```
background-position: 100% 100%;
background-size: cover;
```

and your manual height

Answer (score -1):

replace your style with below code : -

```
background: url(header.jpg); background-size: 100%; position: center;
```